# Wrap a raster at the 180° meridian

Tags: r

I have a raster file that extends longitudinally from 0° to 360°. Using R, I'd like to wrap the raster at 180°, so that longitudes between 180° and 360° are translated to the interval [-180°, 0°]. Is there an existing function or package that can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `raster` package:

```
library(raster)
x <- raster(somefilename)
rotate(x)
```

"rotate" does this task (0/360 to -180/180), *and that is all it does*.
Otherwise it's reasonably straightforward to `crop()` to separate longitude ranges, `shift()` one of them in "x", and `merge()` them back together.

See `?rotate` and `findMethods("rotate")[["Raster"]]` for details of what the function does.